# Facebook leadgen webhook subscribe doesn't work

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm Getting success response from my code, getting new leads in facebook, but nothing is posted to webhook.site.
What am I missing??

```
        function subscribe(id, token) {
            FB.api('/' + id + '/subscribed_apps',
                'post',
                {
                    object: 'page', subscribed_fields: "leadgen", access_token: token, callback_url: "https://webhook.site/93e65665-xxxxxx-xxxx"
                }, function (response) {
                    if (response && response.success) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
        };
```

My app is LIVE and has manage_pages & subscribe permissions.

Comment: Have you try this Test tool to test your webhook notification https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing/